# Obtain Sum, Product, Difference, and Quotient using Javascript Dialog Boxes + Display Results

Tags: javascript, integer, sum, dialog, multiplication

I'm trying to develop a Javascript program that will prompt the user to enter two integers, and then display the sum, product, difference, and quotient of these two integers. Right now it's only displaying the sum. I don't actually know if the multiply, subtract, and divide commands are executing. Here is the link to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xsdztwoc/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <title>Integer Application</title>
  <script>

     var firstNumber; // first string entered by user
     var secondNumber; // second string entered by user
     var number1; // first number to add
     var number2; // second number to add
     var sum; // sum of number1 and number2
     var product; //product of number1 and number2
     var difference; //difference of number1 and number2
     var quotient; //quotient of number1 and number2

     // read in first number from user as a string
     firstNumber = window.prompt( "Enter first integer" );

     // read in second number from user as a string
     secondNumber = window.prompt( "Enter second integer" );

     // convert numbers from strings to integers
     number1 = parseInt( firstNumber ); 
     number2 = parseInt( secondNumber );

     sum = number1 + number2; // add the numbers
     product = number1 * number2; //multiply the integers
     difference = number1 - number2; //subtract the integers
     quotient = number1 / number2; //divide the integers

     // display the results
     document.writeln( "<h1>The sum is " + sum + "</h1>" );
     document.writeIn( "<h1>The product is " + product + "</h1>");
     document.writeIn
     ( "<h1>The difference is " + difference + "</h1>");
     document.writeIn( "<h1>The quotient is " + quotient + "</h1>");
    </script>
    </head><body></body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: the issue was purely using an i instead of an l for function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/xsdztwoc/2/)

The issue appears to simply be that you are using `document.writeIn` but that isn't a function.  You want to use: `document.writeln` which stands for writeLine

**JS**

```
// display the results
document.writeln( "<h1>The sum is " + sum + "</h1>" );
document.writeln( "<h1>The product is " + product + "</h1>");
document.writeln( "<h1>The difference is " + difference + "</h1>");
document.writeln( "<h1>The quotient is " + quotient + "</h1>");
```